# QEMU not booting (in console mode)

Tags: qemu

I am trying to boot QEMU in a terminal.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu.img -cdrom ubuntu-16.04.6-server-amd64.iso -m 2048 -boot d -nographic
```

`ubuntu.img` is a blank disk image to install Ubuntu on and the `-cdrom` is downloaded from the Ubuntu website.

I see the following output:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'ubuntu.img' and probing guessed raw.
     Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
     Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
```

And then nothing else.

Is this a fatal error? Do I need to do something else to boot Ubuntu? I can access the monitor (`C-a c`), but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions relating to software development. This question would be better suited to e.g. https://superuser.com (or possibly https://unix.stackexchange.com).